# latency calculation of service bus queue

Tags: angularjs, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

we have the several component in the application which communicate via service bus queue and topics. We wanted to build the analytics on top of it using the angular JS. We wanted to show the queue length and average time of latency at every min and hour depending upon the selection. kindly let me know how we can get this information ... from angula we need to call web api which calculates the data and show it in liner charts or we need to use the stream analytics Below is the sample screen where x-axis will be time and Y- axis will be total number of count of messages  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out ASB's Metrics REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/Service-Bus-Entity-Metrics-REST-APIs
Though I am not sure it will provide everything you want out of the box. Specifically latency info is not there - have a feeling you'd need to collect and store it yourself.
Also take a look at 3rd party ASB monitoring products e.g. https://www.manageengine.com/products/applications_manager/azure-service-bus-monitoring.html - though I personally have not used them.